# HttpURLConnection: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to use HttpURLClient to send some POST data to a server using the `HttpRestClient` class shown below. When executing

```
conn.setDoInput(true);
```

I get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
```

I uninstalled the app, and still get the same error.

In all the example I've seen openConnection is called before `setDoInput`. If, as its name suggests, `openConnection` opens a connection, it should never be used before `setDoInput, right? What am I missing?

Maybe at some point it crashed before executing `disconnect`. Could that be the reason? If so, how can I disconnect the old connection?

```
public class HttpRestClient {
static public int post(String urlStr, List<NameValuePair> data){

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

    try {

        URL url = new URL(urlStr);


        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getQuery(data));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

        String dude = readIt(is);

        return 1;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
    finally {
        if(conn!=null) conn.disconnect();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you are connecting to a connection that is not yet disconnected due to the static function you are using

Comment: try to remove `conn.connect();` completely (you don't need it). Still got the problem? If yes, then please edit your post and show us the stacktrace.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I can see no problem regarding `static`.

Comment: @hgoebl thanks, I removed the useless `conn.connect()`

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin it seems not to be a problem: I tried to execute several requests at the same time using my static function and it worked, so I guess it opens a different connection every time.

Comment: @jul 'at the same time' is not even physically possible ;) did you use it an a multithreaded environment?

Answer (score 13):

This might be due to watches while debugging in your IDE. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906562/illegal-state-exception-already-connected-when-using-httpurlconnection/38072310#38072310).
It happened to me and was hard to discover.

Comment: That was the answer for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You called both of `conn.setDoInput(true);` and `conn.setDoOutput(true);`. Use one of them:

- `setDoOutput(true)` is used for `POST` and `PUT` requests.
- `setDoInput(true)` is used for `GET` request.

The connection you made was confused, it can't decide which request should be used.

In your code:

```
static public int post(String urlStr, List<NameValuePair> data){
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false"); // must be set
    try {
        ...
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        // and connect to server, if needed
        conn.connect();
        ...
    }
....
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be a misleading exception. See this defect for Jersey-2 https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2729

The link has been updated:
https://github.com/javaee/jersey/issues/3001

Basically the issue is jersey was throwing invalid exception. The real issue in my case was that the connection was refused from the server.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Fixed link URL again