# "Illegal State Exception: Already Connected" when using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I get an illegal state exception when i set DoOutput to true.

```
public boolean sendLinksToMaster(String ipport, List<String> links){

        boolean sent = false;
        String[] tokens = ipport.split(":");    
        String data = edu.cis555.searchengine.utils.Utils.generateLinks(links);
        HttpURLConnection conn=null;
        try{
            String encodedData = URLEncoder.encode(data, "UTF-8");
        try{

                String ip =tokens[0];
                String port = tokens[1];
                String path = edu.cis555.searchengine.utils.Constants.URL_ADD_LINK;
                System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
                URL u = new URL("http", ip, Integer.parseInt(port),"/"+path);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
                //ERROR IN THIS LINE
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                OutputStream stream = conn.getOutputStream();
                stream.write(encodedData.getBytes());
                stream.close();

                if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                    sent=true;

            //  LOG.debug(conn.getResponseCode());
                conn.disconnect();
            }catch(MalformedURLException mfe){
                LOG.debug(mfe.getMessage());
                if(conn!=null){
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                LOG.debug(ioe.getMessage());
                if(conn!=null){
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            LOG.debug(e.getMessage());
            if(conn!=null){
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return sent;

    }
```

The stack trace displayed for the same is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
at java.net.URLConnection.setDoOutput(Unknown Source)
at edu.upenn.cis455.xpathengine.utils.pool.ThreadPool.sendLinksToMaster(ThreadPool.java:357)
at edu.upenn.cis455.xpathengine.utils.pool.ThreadPool$Worker.processAndAddToQueue(ThreadPool.java:314)
at edu.upenn.cis455.xpathengine.utils.pool.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:269)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I don't see anything I am doing wrong with sending the request. Could anyone point out what is missing or what am I doing wrong

Comment: Based on the source for HTTPUrlConnection, it looks like it expects those methods (`setDoOutput` and `setRequestMethod`) to be called *before* the connection is open, which shouldn't be happening until you call `conn.connect()` Your code also looks similar in structure to the [URLConnection sample code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)

Comment: @Chris exactly, I've been digging around URLConnection source code to see what is going on, and the error shouldn't happen at all.

Comment: Hmm... Trying this myself I'm not able to reproduce your issue - I just simplified it enough to throw it into a standalone main method, hardcoded the URL to http://docs.oracle.com, called `url.openConnection()` and stepped through `conn.setDoOutput / conn.setRequestMethod` without errors (verifying that `connected==false` at each step) - it wasn't opened until I called `conn.getOutputStream()`

Comment: I am sending request to a web application hosted on tomcat on the same machine. Could that be causing an issue?

Comment: You should only be getting that issue if your code is reusing an open `HttpURLConnection` instead of creating a new one every time (as per your above code).  Are you able to reproduce your issue if you simplify it into a standalone main method as I did? If not, then there is clearly some difference between what you're running here and that standalone class, and that should help you debug it.

Comment: arpitpanwar: Could you resolve this? This is happening to me too.
@Chris: the problem could be because of connection pooling. Its picking up a reusable connection. Which is why you are not seeing it in the standalone mode.

Comment: @Rohitesh I was able to get around this problem by synchronizing access to this method.

Comment: @arpitpanwar: Synchronizing is also NOT solving the problem for me! :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpURLConnection: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738940/httpurlconnection-java-lang-illegalstateexception-already-connected)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I got the same problem and solved it. In my case, it was caused because I had a forgotten watch for `connection.getResponseCode()` in my debugging interface in NetBeans. Hope it might help others making the same mistake.

If you have any watch relative to the response value of the request, such as `getResponseCode()`, `getResponseMessage()`, `getInputStream()` or even just `connect()`, you will get this error in debugging mode.

All of the previous methods implicitly call `connect()` and fire the request. So when you reach `setDoOutput`, the connection is already made.

Comment: Wow! I was having the same issue, and sure enough i had an expression in my debug window for conn.getResponseCode() ... I removed this and it started worked. not sure why you got a downvote, but i just upvoted it

Comment: Thanks. I was sure this would help others as it is not obvious to debug ;)

Comment: Thanks. It helped me.

Comment: You're amazing sir. I had exactly the same expression inside my watches in Eclipse. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Incredible how many developers fall into the very same trap :-)

Comment: This is the issue with implicit behaviours ;)

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the watches as mentioned in the previous comment, it might also occur if there is something wrong with the connection. For example:

I was setting a property:`post.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "<>")` after writing into OutPut Stream like `post.getOutputStream().write(jsonBody.getBytes("UTF-8"));`

It was like:

```
post.getOutputStream().write(jsonBody.getBytes("UTF-8"))
post.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "<>")
```

In this case, I was also getting "Already Connected". To fix it I made it like:

```
post.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "<>")
post.getOutputStream().write(jsonBody.getBytes("UTF-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it is as easy as make sure you do not have http in stead of https.

Answer (score -3):

put the  stream.close();
in finally block

Comment: The code execution never reaches stream.close(). The exception is raised  as soon as I call setDoOutput

Comment: try kill the java process and then test your code again