# HttpURLConnection Already connected

Tags: java, illegalstateexception, httpconnection, openstack-swift

I'm trying to replicate this, [the copy sentence from openstack swift v1](http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-objectstorage-v1.html#copyObject) (which works just fine):

```
curl -i $publicURL/GXPrueba/StorageAPI/PruebaStorageCopy.png -X PUT -H "X-Auth-Token:  $token" -H "X-Copy-From: /GXPrueba/StorageAPI/PruebaStorage.png" -H "Content-Length: 0"
```

Like this:

```
private void copy(String originContainer, String origin, String destinationContainer, String destination) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(storageUrl + DELIMITER + destinationContainer + DELIMITER + destination);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Auth-Token", authToken);
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Copy-From", DELIMITER + originContainer + DELIMITER + origin);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            System.err.println("Error while copying the object: " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
        conn.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.err.println("Error while copying the object: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error while copying the object: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And I keep getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected` exception at different lines everytime.
I already tried the other solutions I found (like removing the `setDoInput`) but nothing seems to work.

Here is the stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
    at java.net.URLConnection.setDoOutput(URLConnection.java:900)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setDoOutput(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:455)
    at javaapplication3.ExternalProviderBluemix.copy(ExternalProviderBluemix.java:212)
    at javaapplication3.ExternalProviderBluemix.copy(ExternalProviderBluemix.java:202)
    at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:39)
C:\Users\lsarni\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\debug.xml:83: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 24 seconds)
```

Comment: Please provide a stack trace. Why aren't you sending anything?

Comment: @EJP I added the stack trace. I don't send anything because I'm asking to make a copy of an object that is already inside the container.

Comment: You should try closing the input stream of the connection. You normally don't need to set the content-length.

Comment: @EJP sending the content-length is necessary according to [this](http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-objectstorage-v1.html#copyObject). Do you mean doing `conn.setDoInput(false);` ? I tried and get the same error in the `conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");` line instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Illegal State Exception: Already Connected" when using HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906562/illegal-state-exception-already-connected-when-using-httpurlconnection)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out the solution to this problem was what @Sharcoux [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906562/illegal-state-exception-already-connected-when-using-httpurlconnection/38072310#38072310), which explained why sometimes it would work just fine.

So to solve this while debugging on NetBeans you need to remove from the watch all the expressions that use conn (such `conn.setDoOutPut()`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same, and I had the same error for all the methods and it was because I had different watchers so when a watcher is created is executed the connection so for that reason connection is already created or in progress.

Advise: remove all the watchers in your debug mode