# Call AsyncTask from ArrayAdapter produces SIGSEGV error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I have an `ArrayList` with a button on each row.  When the button on the `ArrayList` is clicked,  a class that extends `AsyncTask` is called to update my database.  When execution reaches `httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true)` in this class, the app crashes while debugging and the below error message is given. If I run the app without the debugger, the app does not crash but it also does not appear to execute the `.php` the file that is called in the class that extends `AsyncTask`.

Among other things, this article

[Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x636f7d89 (code=1). How can it be tracked down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked)

suggest a common reason for SIGSEV  is the Canvas drawing something that is null. This may be the problem I have since I have a null pointer dereference in the error message.

> How do I troubleshoot and/or resolve the error message below?  My
>   relevant code follows the error message.

---

EDIT 190910

The error listed below may have something to do with calling notifyDataSetChanged() before the asyncTask finishes.  I am going to edit my code to call notifyDataSetChanged() after the asyncTask finishes.  I will report back once I have the result.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phoneTV"
        android:layout_width="176dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:hint="(999) 999-9999"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/phoneTV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`AdapterAcceptedNumber.java`

```
    public class AdapterAcceptedNumber extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    List<String> acceptedNums = new ArrayList();
    Context context;

    public AdapterAcceptedNumber(Context context,int resource){
        super(context,resource);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return acceptedNums.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return acceptedNums.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View row;
        row = convertView;

        AdapterAcceptedNumber.ViewHolder holder = null;

        //row is null until user moves the list on the screen
        if(row == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_text_button, parent, false);

            holder = new AdapterAcceptedNumber.ViewHolder();
            holder.acceptedNumTV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.phoneTV);
            holder.delButt = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.delButton);

           // holder.delButt.setOnClickListener((PhoneAcceptedActivity)this.getContext());
            holder.delButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String CollectorPhoneNumberToDelete = getNumber(position);
                    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.preferenceKeyFile),MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String gid = sharedPref.getString("groupID","error");

                    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(context);
                    backgroundWorker.execute("DeleteLogin",CollectorPhoneNumberToDelete,gid);
                }
            });

            row.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder=(AdapterAcceptedNumber.ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        String digits = acceptedNums.get(position);
        holder.acceptedNumTV.setText(digits);

        return row;
    }

    public void updateRecord(List<String> phoneNums){
        acceptedNums = phoneNums;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void delPhoneNumber(int positionToDelete){
        acceptedNums.remove(positionToDelete);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public String getNumber(int position){
        return acceptedNums.get(position);
    }



    private static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView acceptedNumTV;
        Button delButt;
    }
    }



    public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    Context context;

    BackgroundWorker(Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
    }


    //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eldh8l8yPew
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];

        String deleteLogin_url = "file.php";


        }else if (type.equals("DeleteLogin")){
            try {
                String phoneNumberToDelete = "";
                String gid = "";
                if(!params[1].equals("null"))
                    phoneNumberToDelete = params[1];
                if(!params[2].equals("null"))
                    gid = params[2];
                URL urlAddress = new URL(deleteLogin_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)urlAddress.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);  //crashes here when debugging
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStreamAddress = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStreamAddress,"UTF-8"));
                String postData = URLEncoder.encode("gid","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(gid,"UTF-8") + "&"
                      + URLEncoder.encode("collectorNumberToDelete","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(phoneNumberToDelete,"UTF-8");  //post to php page
                bufferedWriter.write(postData);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStreamAddress.close();

                InputStream inputStreamAddress = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                //BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));  worked for local host
                BufferedReader bufferedReaderAddress = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStreamAddress));
                resultAddress = "";
                String lineAddress = "";
                while ( (lineAddress = bufferedReaderAddress.readLine()) != null){
                    resultAddress += lineAddress;
                }
                bufferedReaderAddress.close();
                inputStreamAddress.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return "goBack";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

`Log:`

```
>2019-09-08 20:34:51.792 8403-9265/com.rc.rentcollection W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method java.net.InetAddress[] libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(java.lang.String, android.system.StructAddrinfo, int)

>2019-09-08 20:34:51.994 8403-9265/com.rc.rentcollection W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method java.lang.String com.rc.rentcollection.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(java.lang.String[])

>2019-09-08 20:34:52.334 8403-9265/com.rc.rentcollection W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method java.lang.String com.rc.rentcollection.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(java.lang.String[])

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.448 8403-9265/com.rc.rentcollection A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xc in tid 9265 (AsyncTask #6), pid 8403 (.rentcollection)

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.500 9277-9277/? E/propClient: PropClient failed to load

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.547 2832-2903/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB: Unsupported attribute type, ignoring 0x8

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.547 2832-2903/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB: unrecognized ifindex 20

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.548 2832-2903/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB: Unsupported attribute type, ignoring 0x8

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.548 2832-2903/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB: unrecognized ifindex 20

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.558 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.559 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Verizon/j7popltevzwpp/j7popltevzw:8.1.0/M1AJQ/J727VPPVRS3BSD1:user/release-keys'

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.559 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '5'

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.559 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.559 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG: pid: 8403, tid: 9265, name: AsyncTask #6  >>> com.rc.rentcollection <<<

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.559 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xc

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.559 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.559 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000000001  x2   0000000000000008  x3   0000000000000003

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.559 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000006fd834190e  x5   0000006fcf0185d8  x6   20646f6874656d20  x7   20646f6874656d20

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.559 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000006fbf502f20  x9   6891c97f3b1a61c6  x10  0000006fcf0185d0  x11  0000000000000010

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.559 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000006fcf0b49d0  x13  6c62617a696d6974  x14  0000000000000028  x15  0000006fbeded000

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.559 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000006fd83ce528  x17  000000705b6fc870  x18  0000006fbf5017cc  x19  0000006fbf502f20

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.559 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000000000000000  x21  0000000000000001  x22  0000006fbf503588  x23  0000000000000000

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.559 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000006fbf502f20  x25  0000006fbf503588  x26  0000006fbeded0a0  x27  0000000000000001

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.559 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000000000000043  x29  0000006fbf502f10  x30  0000006fd8246768

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.559 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000006fbf502df0  pc   0000006fd7e8027c  pstate 0000000060000000

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.582 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.582 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000000000dd27c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::PrettyMethod(bool)+56)

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.582 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00000000004a3764  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::QuickDeliverException()+564)

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.582 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0000000000521d14  /system/lib64/libart.so (artDeliverPendingExceptionFromCode+8)

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.582 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00000000005507a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+248)

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.582 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000000000547588  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.582 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00000000000dd0b4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.582 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000000000046bca4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.582 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 000000000046ce34  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+772)

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.582 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0000000000493718  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1120)

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.582 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0000000000069974  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)

>2019-09-08 20:34:54.583 9278-9278/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 000000000001f864  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.507 2685-2685/? E//system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_01

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.512 3218-9279/? W/ActivityManager: crash : com.rc.rentcollection,0

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.515 3218-9279/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.rc.rentcollection/.PhoneAcceptedActivity

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.519 2643-2643/? E/audit: type=1701 audit(1567992895.507:817): auid=4294967295 uid=10221 gid=10221 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 pid=8403 comm=4173796E635461736B202336 exe="/system/bin/app_process64" sig=11

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.525 3218-3294/? W/Choreographer: Frame time is 12.38591 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase.

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.528 3218-3235/? W/zygote64: kill(-8376, 9) failed: No such process

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.544 3218-3235/? W/zygote64: kill(-8376, 9) failed: No such process

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.545 3218-3325/? W/InputDispatcher: channel ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.545 3218-3325/? E/InputDispatcher: channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.545 3218-3325/? W/InputDispatcher: channel ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.545 3218-3325/? E/InputDispatcher: channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.549 3218-3325/? W/InputDispatcher: channel ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.549 3218-3325/? E/InputDispatcher: channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.550 3218-3325/? W/InputDispatcher: channel ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.550 3218-3325/? E/InputDispatcher: channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.550 3218-3235/? W/zygote64: kill(-8403, 9) failed: No such process

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.553 3218-3995/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.557 3218-16036/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.579 8496-8496/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1545 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:669 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:669 com.samsung.android.sm.common.SmartManagerReceiver.a:240 com.samsung.android.sm.common.SmartManagerReceiver.onReceive:119 

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.580 3218-3707/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.583 3218-3969/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.599 501-629/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.618 9281-9281/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.618 9281-9281/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.618 9281-9281/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.621 9281-9281/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SM-J727VPP_8.1.0_0008, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.627 3218-3235/? W/zygote64: kill(-8233, 9) failed: No such process

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.628 3218-3242/? W/ActivityManager: setHasOverlayUi called on unknown pid: 8403

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.632 3218-3235/? W/zygote64: kill(-8233, 9) failed: No such process

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.638 3218-3235/? W/zygote64: kill(-8233, 9) failed: No such process

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.643 3218-3235/? W/zygote64: kill(-8233, 9) failed: No such process

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.644 3218-9006/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.644 3218-3233/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.644 3218-3234/? W/Looper: Dispatch took 119ms on android.ui, h=Handler (com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$UiHandler) {4215cc} cb=null msg=1

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.648 3218-3235/? W/zygote64: kill(-8233, 9) failed: No such process

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.707 8533-8612/? W/PkgUtils: p: com.rc.rentcollection, u:0

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.716 9302-9302/? E/propClient: PropClient failed to load

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.750 9305-9305/? E/propClient: PropClient failed to load

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.750 9304-9304/? E/propClient: PropClient failed to load

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.764 9307-9307/? E/propClient: PropClient failed to load

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.855 9281-9312/com.rc.rentcollection W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

>2019-09-08 20:34:55.872 9281-9314/com.rc.rentcollection W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

>2019-09-08 20:34:56.363 9307-9307/? E/propClient: PropClient failed to load

>2019-09-08 20:34:56.370 9307-9307/? W/ADebug: Failed to get property persist.sys.media.traces

>2019-09-08 20:34:56.390 9307-9307/? E/appproc: Enhanced Zygote ASLR: ro.knox.enhance.zygote.aslr != 1. Enhanced Zygote ASLR is DISABLED!

>2019-09-08 20:34:56.733 3218-3294/? W/Choreographer: Frame time is 13.006558 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase.

>2019-09-08 20:34:56.836 9307-9307/? E/SemAffinityControl: SemAffinityControl: registerfunction enter

>2019-09-08 20:34:56.896 3218-3242/? E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: com_qualcomm_qtiperformance_native_perf_io_prefetch_start

>2019-09-08 20:34:56.920 9307-9334/? W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {384f244} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {384f244} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
        at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:545)
        at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:662)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:631)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:601)
        at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:357)
        at android.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver.send(ResultReceiver.java:57)
        at com.android.internal.os.IResultReceiver$Stub.onTransact(IResultReceiver.java:58)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:705)

>2019-09-08 20:34:56.957 9338-9338/? E/propClient: PropClient failed to load

>2019-09-08 20:34:57.063 3218-3294/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{df00e56 u0 Splash Screen com.rc.rentcollection EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0, caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:748 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:732 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5523 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:553 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.lambda$-com_android_server_wm_DisplayContent_21292:465 

>2019-09-08 20:34:57.312 9338-9338/? E/propClient: PropClient failed to load

>2019-09-08 20:34:57.314 9338-9338/? W/ADebug: Failed to get property persist.sys.media.traces

>2019-09-08 20:34:57.320 9338-9338/? E/appproc: Enhanced Zygote ASLR: ro.knox.enhance.zygote.aslr != 1. Enhanced Zygote ASLR is DISABLED!

>2019-09-08 20:34:57.494 9338-9338/? E/SemAffinityControl: SemAffinityControl: registerfunction enter

>2019-09-08 20:34:57.512 9338-9347/? W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {81641c0} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {81641c0} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
        at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:545)
        at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:662)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:631)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:601)
        at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:357)
        at android.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver.send(ResultReceiver.java:57)
        at com.android.internal.os.IResultReceiver$Stub.onTransact(IResultReceiver.java:58)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:705)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.  Unfortunately, I did not give enough information in the original question.  I made three mistakes:

1)  Calling notifyDataSetChanged() while the AsynTask was executing appeared to cause a problem.  I altered program flow by making my AsynTask an inner class so I could call the adapter and execute notifyDataSetChanged() after the AsynTask was complete.

2)  I was missing a parentheses in my .php file.  The problem was in a part of the file that I commented out when testing the file.  I had 
`$var = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["var"];`
and I should of had
`$var = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["var"]);`

3)  The final problem created an IllegalStateException.  This post helped me resolve that problem ["Illegal State Exception: Already Connected" when using HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906562/illegal-state-exception-already-connected-when-using-httpurlconnection).

I hope this information can help someone else.